# What action hook would I use to update post meta when viewing a post in Wordpress admin?

Tags: php, wordpress, hook, action

Example URL: mywebsite.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=1234&action=edit

I have found hooks that fire when a post is created/edited/status changed, but nothing that works for just viewing a post.

I need to check some meta data and update it before the post is displayed to the user

I have tried several hooks already but none let me edit post meta at the correct time (when viewing a post)

Solution: Adding this to admin_init allowed me to update post meta for a given post after the post data was loaded

```php
if (isset($_GET['post']) && (isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'edit'))
{
   $post = get_post($_GET['post']);

   if ($post->post_type == 'program')
   {
      // do stuff
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**save_post** hook in your case
what you are trying to do show your code

Comment: save_post fires when a post is updated, I need to look at meta data before it is displayed.

Comment: Questions and doubts can be asked in comments. Answers need supporting information

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there's a hook so you could either add one manually or use something like this

```
global $pagenow;
if (is_admin() && $pagenow == 'post.php') {

    // editing a post

}
```

Comment: This solution would probably also work